# LVM error on boot causing fall back to initramfs

Tags: boot, lvm, initramfs

I've recently updated Ubuntu from an older LTS release (12.04) to 14.04 LTS and upon reboot, ubuntu fails to load and an error in `/sbin/lvm` is shown:

```
There appears to be one or more degraded LVM volumes, and your root device may 
depend on the LVM volumes being online. 
One or more of the following LVM volumes are degraded:
/sbin/lvm: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libreadline.so.5: undefined symbol: PC
Gave up waiting for root device...
ALERT! /dev/mapper/my-server-root does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

It seems like the **/sbin/lvm: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libreadline.so.5: undefined symbol: PC** is the culprit, and I suppose that `/sbin/lvm` wasn't correctly linked with the appropriate libraries, causing the boot image to be unable to run LVM at all, so the LVM volumes does not load.

**What I have tried**

1. Running `lvm` in the initramfs shell returns the same error about symbol lookup.
2. Removing `/usr/local/lib/libreadline.so.5` and running `lvm` will make it throw an error about `libreadline.so.5` not being available instead.
3. `vgchange` is not a valid command (I assume it requires `lvm` and it should be ran using `lvm vgchange -ay` instead?)

I *guess* that I should try to re-build the boot image to include a correct copy of `lvm`. However I am not sure how to do that (should I boot a 14.04 live disk, and install `lvm2`, or should I do some more steps? How can I modify initramfs and fix it?) and I am afraid I mess up the existing LVM configuration. How should I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some tinkering in the liveCD, I have resolved the problem as follows:

1. Boot from Live CD and from Live CD `sudo apt-get install lvm2`.
2. Check the LVs from `lvdisplay`, and figure out the boot partition from `lsblk`
3. Mount the LV using `lvchange -a y`
4. Mount the root LV and the boot partition, e.g.

   sudo mkdir /new

   sudo mount /dev/mapper/my-root /new

   sudo mount /dev/sda1 /new/boot
5. `chroot` to `/new` and re-install `lvm2` from there.
6. Go to `/usr/local/lib/` and **remove** (or move) `libreadline.so.5`.
7. `ldconfig`
8. Try to run `lvm` from chroot, you will see an error about `/var` not being available, instead of the usual `libreadline.so.5` error.
9. `update-initramfs -u -v`. You will see `libreadline.so.5` won't be copied from `/usr/local/lib` anymore, but instead from `x86_64`! This is the correct shared library.
10. Reboot. `lvm` should now load correctly in initramfs, so it mounts the root partition successfully and you can now boot.

Comment: Number 9 saved my day! :D